# NSIS - Set the working directory for a process before running it

Tags: java, process, nsis

As above.
I'm specifically running a Java program using ExecWait, by invoking java.exe and passing the classname. The application I'm running relies on relative paths and has to be run from a specific directory, however when I directly call java, it simply uses the installer location as the current directory and fails.

Is there a way to get around this?

**Update:** Here's my commandline:

```
ExecWait "$INSTDIR\MyApp\jre\bin\java.exe -cp $INSTDIR\MyApp\lib\*; MyJavaClassName"
```

Comment: Could you post some command lines?

Comment: Done, I'm just calling my app's bundled JRE along with the class name.

Comment: You should fix your quotes just to be safe: ExecWait '"$instdir\app.exe" "param 1" param2 "para m3"' (Paths etc should be quoted)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[SetOutPath](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#setoutpath) sets the current/working directory for the process, it should be inherited by the child process...

```
Push $OUTDIR
SetOutPath $myspecialdir
ExecWait '"$instdir\myapp.exe"'
Pop $OUTDIR
SetOutPath $OUTDIR # Optional if working directory does not matter for the rest of the code
```

or

```
SetOutPath $myspecialdir
ExecWait '"$instdir\myapp.exe"'
SetOutPath $instdir
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that this would also set the current directory :)