# How to run exe files in NSIS Script?

Tags: exe, nsis

In InnoSetup, there is a part called **run** which will execute the exe, batch file and msi. We can also give command line parameters to this run.

I provide the Innosetup sample:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\msdirent.exe ";
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\NETCFSetupv2.msi""" ; Check:ShouldInstallComCtlUpdate ;
```

But in NSISS Script, how to run my exe and also I have to provide command line arguments to the concerned exe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following  commands

```
Exec "$APPS\msdirent.exe"
```

For Command Line Args,

```
Exec "$APPS\msdirent.exe 1"
```

For Adding msdirent.exe to the installer,

```
SetOutPath "$APPS"
File "localpath\msdirent.exe"

Exec "$APPS\msdirent.exe 1"
```

Comment: @ Sivakg: How to pack that msdirent.exe into the installer?

Comment: You need to quote these paths correctly, see the NSIS manual or my answer for examples!

Comment: @Sivakg: How to pack that msdirent.exe into the uninstaller?

Answer (score 27):

You have [3 NSIS instructions](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#exec) that can start a new process: `Exec`, `ExecWait` and `ExecShell` (Internally the first two use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the last one uses [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

In all cases `SetOutPath` sets the [working directory for the child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655408/nsis-set-the-working-directory-for-a-process-before-running-it).

It is important to get the quoting correct since NSIS has 3 quote characters and windows paths with spaces should be quoted with `"`:

```
ExecWait '"$instdir\myapp.exe"'
Exec '"$instdir\otherapp.exe" param1 "par am 2" param3'
```

Comment: @ Anders: Thanks for your answer. I upvote your answer but Sivakg is the one who give the answer first.

Comment: @karthik Well, his current answer is wrong, those Exec's will not work on all systems...